# server.arg("plain") is not working in some cases in ESP8266 Webserver

Tags: html, arduino, webserver, esp8266

I found a post server example in the ESP8266-Webserver-example list. Then I modified it to reach my need. I wrote my own HTML code and hosted that site in my ESP8266. The code is:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>

#ifndef STASSID
#define STASSID "ssid"
#define STAPSK  "pass"
#endif

const char* ssid     = STASSID;
const char* password = STAPSK;

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

const int led = LED_BUILTIN;

const String postForms = "";


void handleRoot() {
  digitalWrite(led, 1);
  server.send(200, "text/html", postForms);
  digitalWrite(led, 0);
}

void handlePlain() {
  if (server.method() != HTTP_POST) {
    digitalWrite(led, 1);
    server.send(405, "text/plain", "Method Not Allowed");
    digitalWrite(led, 0);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(led, 1);
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "POST body was:\n" + server.arg("plain"));
    digitalWrite(led, 0);
  }
}

void setup(void) {
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led, 0);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  if (MDNS.begin("esp8266")) {
    Serial.println("MDNS responder started");
  }

  server.on("/", handleRoot);

  server.on("/postplain/", handlePlain);

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop(void) {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

And when I enter this HTML code inside of the postForms string, I get the correct output.
Here:

```
<html>

<head>

<title>ESP8266 Web Server POST handling</title>

<style>

body { background-color: cyan; font-family: Arial; Color: Black}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Let us know what you think!</h1><br>

<form method="post" enctype="text/plain" action="/postplain/" >

<input type="text" name="Comment:" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

The output after submitting "Hello" using the above HTML code:

```
POST body was:
Comment:=Hello
```

But when I use the `<textarea>` element instead of the `<input>` element in the HTML code:

```
<html>

<head>

<title>ESP8266 Web Server POST handling</title>

<style>

body { background-color: cyan; font-family: Arial; Color: Black}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Let us know what you think!</h1><br>

<form method="post" enctype="text/plain" action="/postplain/" >
<textarea rows = "10" cols = "60">Hello</textarea> <br><br><br>
<input type="submit">

</form>
```

Then the output is:

```
POST body was:
```

Using the `<textarea>` element, the server.arg("plain") function is not printing the input value.
Am I doing something wrong? Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question myself after trying for some time. I need to add the `name` attribute inside the `<textarea>` element like this: `<textarea rows = "10" cols = "60" name = "somewhat_name">Hello</textarea>`

The implementation of the server.arg() function seems to be a bit weird, it doesn't return the input value unless the `<input>` or `<textarea>` element has the `name` attribute with something in it.

Comment: It is not weird, it is about understand how html tags actually works. Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form. See [HTTML <input> name attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_name.asp)